# Why can't I use FLASK "render_template" when there is a variable specified in my route?

Tags: flask, endpoint

I am trying to set up an email confirmation system for new users on a small site.
When I attempt to use a variable in my @app.route() I get the error "werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'confirm_email'. Did you forget to specify values ['token']?"

I am navigating the url "site.domain/confirm/randomtext" directly and recieving the error.
However if I return text instead of a render_template the text works just fine!

I know its something I am overlooking and this is the first time I can remember seeing this issue and not being able to think of a fix.
What would cause this? Do render_templates not work with app.route(/)?

````
@app.route('/confirm/<token>')
def confirm_email(token):
    websitedata = Website.query.first()
    try:
        email = confirm_token(token)
    except:
        return render_template('confirmemailpage.html', websitedata=websitedata,resp='20')
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if user==None:
        return render_template('filename.html')
    if user.confirmed:
        return render_template('confirmemailpage.html', websitedata=websitedata,resp='20')
    else:
        user.confirmed = True
        user.confirmed_on = datetime.datetime.now()
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('confirmemailpage.html', websitedata=websitedata,resp='22')
    ```


Error
````

werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'confirm_email'. Did you forget to specify values ['token']?

Traceback (most recent call last)